# Linux - Escape key not working, regular escape bound to Shift-Escape

Tags: linux, keyboard

I installed Zenwalk Linux today. I found that the Escape key is not bound to anything (at least from what I can tell) but instead what Escape would normally do (close programs, opening the vim command-line, etc.) Shift-Escape is bound to.

While it's not a huge deal, it's an extra keystroke I'm not used to I'm not interested in relearning for only one machine.

Does anyone have any insight as to how I could correct this?
I'm using the qwerty/us.map.

Here is the dumpkeys information related to Escape.

```
keymaps 0-2,4-6,8-9,12
keycode   1 = Escape          
        alt     keycode   1 = Meta_Escape     
        shift   alt     keycode   1 = Meta_Escape     
        control alt     keycode   1 = Meta_Escape
```

**The keyboard is NOT broken.**

As I mentioned in a (poorly formatted) comment to @petesh I think I need to set Escape to equal Meta_Escape in a way that dumpkeys looks like this:

```
keymaps 0-2,4-6,8-9,12
keycode   1 = Escape     
        keycode   1 = Meta_Escape     
        alt     keycode   1 = Meta_Escape     
        shift   alt     keycode   1 = Meta_Escape     
        control alt     keycode   1 = Meta_Escape
```

How can I go about this?

Comment: There's a corresponding `loadkeys` command which allows you to remap.

Comment: In the context of the dumpkeys output, I think the goal would be along the lines of :
    keycode   1 = Escape \         
        keycode   1 = Meta_Escape \
        alt     keycode   1 = Meta_Escape \    
        shift   alt     keycode   1 = Meta_Escape \

How would loadkeys help?

Answer (score 5):

I had similar problem. If you are using KDE plasma then open `System Settings > Shortcuts`, find there `Activity Manager` and remove `Esc` under `custom shortcuts`.

Comment: If you can't find which shortcut the Esc key is bound to, then add a shortcut to Search, it will complain about double binding, say yes and remove the old binding. Then remove shortcut for Search. The esc key is now unbound.